# Basic Lightning component audio player

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, custom-controller

I'm trying to get a hold of the Saleforce stack and so far i have created a custom controller and have access to the data i need on a visual force page. However i'm not sure how to translate this to a lightning component.

As an example here's my simple vfp...

```
<HTML>
<script src="staticResource"></script>
<script>
  audiojs.events.ready(function() {
    var as = audiojs.createAll();
  });
</script>
<audio src="mp3URL" preload="auto" />
</HTML>
```

I know that i use the following code to load my script

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.audiojs}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
```

But i'm not really sure how to translate the rest of my code to the component. What i would like to do is have a quick action button where a user can play audio stored on a salesforce object without having to switch pages.

Comment: The HTML you have there is neither a Visualforce page nor a Lightning component - it's just HTML. Have you had a chance to work through the basic Lightning component Trailhead modules? It's not clear what exactly you're asking at the moment.

Comment: How do i use javascript from an external library after i import it?

Comment: So you want to stream an audio file which is stored somewhere on Salesforce? That's quite unusual, I don't think I've ever seen a requirement like this.

Comment: Create a client side controller with afterScriptsLoaded function in it. Place that JS snippet from script tags there. Also, do check audio API compatibility with locker service here: http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV